# iOS5: UIWebView doesn’t display Gmail after some attachment files were opened

Tags: uiwebview, webkit, gmail, ios5, attachment

Is there any fix/workaround for the problem?

Summary:

On iOS5 devices/simulators, applications with UIWebView do not display Gmail after some kinds of attachment files were opened, such as .pdf, .txt, or .xml. I build some simple apps with UIWebView, which have the searchBar, the goBack button and so on. They work perfectly on iPhone 4.3 devices/simulators when they are built for iOS 4.3, but they do not on those of 5.0. The projects built for iOS5 also have the same problems.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Build an app targeted for iOS 4.3 or 5.0 with UIWebView, which has at least a goBack button and a searchBar for URLs.
2. Run the app on an iOS5 device / simulator.
3. Log in to Gmail in the app.
4. Open a pdf (txt / xml) attachment of one of your emails. 
   (This problem does not happen when you open a Microsoft office file supported by UIWebView, such as word, excel and powerpoint.)
5. Go back to the previous page by pushing the goBack button, or enter the URL “http://mail.google.com” in the searchBar.
6. The UIWebView shows a white blank.
7. After that you can never see your Gmail page.

Expected Results:

You can go back to the previous email (when you push the goBack button), or go to the top of Gmail page (when you enter the Gmail URL).

Actual Results:

The UIWebView just shows a white blank, and never let you see any Gmail page.

Regression:

Occur:
- iOS Deployment Target 4.3, run on iOS 5.0 devices / simulators
- iOS Deployment Target 5.0, run on iOS 5.0 devices / simulators

Does Not Occur:
- iOS Deployment Target 4.3, run on iOS 4.3 devices / simulators

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but could not fix it. I suggest you one of the workaround.
If your UIWebView goes to "mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com" , the Go back
action is wrong. So when the URL is detected, you had better create another view and load the attachment on it. The second has the GO back button however when it is pushed down you discard the second view then return to the first view via IBAction method. It works on iOS4 and iOS5.

my sample code is following.

```
-(BOOL) firstView:(UIWebView *)view
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)req
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)nType{
    NSString *strurl=[[[req URL] standardizedURL] absoluteString];
    NSRange range=[strurl rangeOfString: @"mail-attachment" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (range.location!=NSNotFound){
        Your2ndViewController *attView = [[Your2ndViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibNameofAnothor" bundle:nil];
        if(attView==nil){
            return NO;
        }
        attView.wvc=self;//mark the first on the second to return the first one
            [attView loadURLWithString:strurl];
        [self.view addSubview:attView.view ];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [attView loadURLWithString:strurl];
        return NO;//Not Load on the first view
    }
    return YES;//Load on the first view
}
```

Your 2nd View which is also UIWebView has a return button and it's handler is following

```
- (IBAction) returnParent:(id)sender
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];//return to the first view
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I confirmed the way you suggested does work. I reported the problem to both Apple and Google. Hope it will be fixed soon!